# How do I offer an Ajax POST response to the user as a download?

Tags: php, jquery, download

I'm trying to include a vCard export function in an existing page full of account information.

The ugly methods would involve 1, submitting a form to the same page, processing it and re-rendering the whole page, or 2, a GET targeting an iframe on the page.  I'd really like to avoid both of those, but I may have to use #2 to achieve the goal.

Right now I have:

```
<input type="image" src="/intra/imgs/icons/vcard.png" onclick="$.post('/intra/vcard.php', { id: '992772', type: 'sponsor'});">
```

Which works in the sense that if I watch XHR activity in Firebug I see the request come back with the correct response, full of vCard formatted data.  However it does not prompt the user to download the response as a file, even though the card is sent with:

```
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$this->name_first}{$this->name_last}.vcf");
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

Comment: You want to POST a download? Dangerous contradiction in terms, I'd find a way that does this as a GET.

Comment: REST adherence is far from being important in this context. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm confused as to what exactly the problem is. Why not just do something like:

```
<input type="image"
       src="/intra/imgs/icons/vcard.png"
       onclick="window.location='/intra/vcard.php?id=992772&type=sponsor';">
```

And then return the appropriate download headers on `vcard.php`? When the browser gets those, it will stay on the same page and prompt for download. You will have to change your code to handle the variables as `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` but you should be using GET for this anyways.

**EDIT** as pointed out in the comments, it would be even more appropriate to do this:

```
<a href="/intra/vcard.php?id=992772&type=sponsor"><img src="/intra/imgs/icons/vcard.png"></a>
```

As then it would be accessible to users with javascript disabled.

Comment: I thought I remembered some behavior like that, but couldn't remember how I'd accomplished it (5 years ago?).  Thanks!

Comment: and why not use <a> instead of onclick?

Comment: This is true. I wasn't even thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can't trigger a download from xhr. Only way I've found is option #2, use an iframe.

Perhaps a jquery plugin (I'm assuming you're using jquery) is an overkill for just this purpose, but [this](http://www.nicolas.rudas.info/jQuery/xajaSubmit.js) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

check if the filename ´{$this->name_first}{$this->name_last}.vcf´) is valid and the http-response in firebug! (tab network, click on the response).

is the content there and correct?
is the content-length correct?
what about the http-status?

Answer (score 0):

Generate you content during post, then redirect to that content.